# error: -bash: wget: command not found - Visual Code - Docker Terminal

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, airflow

In my Visual Studio code, in the terminal, when I run

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.8.txt -O requirements-python3.7.txt
```

it results in error: `-bash: wget: command not found.`
[image]

On my WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, in the same computer, it works normally.

What should I do?

Comment: Install wget -- it's a separate program, not part of bash.

Comment: ...if this is a Docker container, make sure the container's setup installs wget. That might be a `RUN apt-get install wget` command, or something else, depending on the details of what base image you're extending &c.

Comment: i tried but i have the same error: airflow@463090d91905:~$ RUN apt-get install wget
-bash: RUN: command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget` in your docker image for a permanent installation.

Or

You run `apt-get update && apt-get install wget` in the terminal for a temporary installation (= until your container is rebuilt).

Comment: How is this thing that works different from what I [suggested in a comment earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580344/error-bash-wget-command-not-found-visual-code-docker-terminal?noredirect=1#comment114190497_64580344), and that was reported not to work?

Comment: apt-get update && apt-get install wget works for me.  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget  it didn't work for me. thank you

Comment: @Gizelly, the `RUN` part should be used if-and-only-if you're adding the command to a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `curl` which is an alternative to `wget` ans is include in bash, so no further installation is needed.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-1.10.12/constraints-3.8.txt -o requirements-python3.7.txt
```